# Era time is not completing

Tags: polkadot, election

I have deployed my blockchain sometime ago and just checked that the era time is stuck, i have tried to `forceNewEra()` using sudo command, i have also tried `forceNewEraAlways()` but it changes the era time to 10 minutes. Than i tried to runtime upgrade the blockchian and it was upgraded successfully but era time was still not updated. Some please help me asap.

[image]

Comment: If you can include a WS address and a Github repo that would be great!

Comment: @Bruno it is not possible to me to share github repo can you please give some idea that how can i correct this or where i have to change.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you made add some custom logic around eras ? Something that we cannot know how it could be affecting the system without checking the code ?
Is it possible for you to share some description on how your system is architected ? I feel that something like that should not happen without modifications to certain parts of the codebase.

Comment: This may be the issue: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/7607#issuecomment-1129752912

Comment: @AlejandroMartínez we haven't done any changes around eras but we did some changes in fee structure, i think that would not be a problem, we just increased the validator count from 10 -> 12 using sudo.

Answer (score 2):

As stated here: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/7607#issuecomment-1129752912

> This situation can happen IFF the chain moves to an emergency condition where the election/staking have failed to trigger a new era. In this case, new sessions are created, but no new era is created, thus no new validator set is also chosen and we stick with the old set.

> This is why the duration of the era is prolonged.

A fix is also proposed within that link.

Comment: I have tired all these solutions but still the problem persists, I don't have governance_fallback function in my code, so don't know if it will work or not, I tried set_emergency_election_result function it didn't worked.
Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Have you generated the appropriate `supports` using [`staking-miner`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/utils/staking-miner) ?

Comment: @AlejandroMartínez it is same as provided by the substrate, we didn't change anything in it.